# Zero Downtime Code Update for Django App

Tags: python, django

Things being used:

1. Supervisor to run uwsgi
2. uwsgi to bring up my Django non-rel 1.6 based ML app (Django Upgrade in process)

I am using Uwsgi to start my Django ML based app. 
But somehow as it has to load a lot of binaries for initialization, it takes about 20-30 seconds for supervisor to restart and load new code.

How can I reduce this time?
or is there any other way to run the Django app so as to reload quickly when code changes?   With ZERO downtime? as Nginx will start throwing 5xx if it can't connect to Django.

Comment: Your question implies other requirements than just code reloading. A ZERO downtime does not exist. To reduce downtime special system architectures have to brought in place. They complexity increases with the reduction of downtime risk. There is nothing you can do with a single Django instance. As a starter you will need multiple Django instances running a failover scenario. nginx offers limited capabilities for this. But actually you question is neither about programming not is there any simple solution that can be a given as an answer here.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks. But we are doing that for one of our projects already. 
I totally agree with you.

This is not a critical environment where we would put in so much efforts to set this up. 

Is there a way using run python manage.py runserver that I can keep the application up and it knows the code has changed and starts serving the new code?

python manage.py runserver does detect code change but I was wondering if it will detect new requirements installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Blue-Green deployment approach.
In this approach, there are two identical server: one is `Blue`, other is `Green`.
At any time, only one of the environments is live, with the live environment serving all production traffic.As you prepare a new release of your software you do your final stage of testing in the green environment. Once the software is working in the green environment, you switch the router so that all incoming requests go to the green environment - the blue one is now idle.

Comment: Thanks. But we are doing that for one of our projects already. 

This is not a critical environment where we would put in so much efforts to set this up. 

Is there a way using run python manage.py runserver that I can keep the application up and it knows the code has changed and starts serving the new code?

 python manage.py runserver does detect code change but I was wondering if it will detect new requirements installed?

Comment: No, @RanvijayJamwal I don't know about that.Please add an answer to this question, if you find one.

Comment: Okay. I will definitely do.